# Flutter/Dart: Image.asset building on different screen

Tags: image, flutter, caching, dart, build

New to Flutter here. In Android Studio I'm watching the Widget rebuild stats to see where I can improve performance, and noticed that I have an Image.asset that is being rebuilt when I hot reload on a different screen. The Image.asset is on my home screen, but it's being rebuilt on the next screen that I navigate to, no matter where I go, but it stops when I go further into a 3rd screen. Do I have to dispose the image somehow on the home screen? I've been going through the docs and searching online and can't find anything.

Comment: It's normal for screens in the navigation stack to rebuild, check here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11655

Comment: Okay. Thank you!